# Is there a way to make my application wait until a script finishes?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have simplified my code for the sake of this question, but basically what happens is this:

```
private void RunScript(string path)
{
    Process.Start(path);
    lblStatus.Text = "Step 6 Complete";
}
```

However, I don't want the label's text to be updated *until* the script finishes running. Is that possible? Or rather, practical / feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your code by this if you want to wait for a maximum given amount of time:

```
 Process.Start(path).WaitForExit(milli seconds);
```

or this if you want to wait possibly forever (usually until it finishes)

```
 Process.Start(path).WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing, I'm sure it will come in handy, but unfortunately I'm writing a utility to help expedite our convoluted patch deployment / update process. The scripts that will be run take a variable amount of time each time we do updates, depending on how many files are being updated (sometimes only a few small critical things, other times huge updates). So I don't think that'd work for this specific problem.

Comment: @sab669 There is an overload that does not have a timeout value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: milli seconds are optional if that's what bothers you. I have updated my answer.

Comment: `wait possibly forever`  - Well the sun is about to burn out and kill us all but by god this install script is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Process.Start(path).WaitForExit(); that will ... wait for the process to exit before continuing.

Becareful if this is on your main UI thread though as the UI will freeze and become unresponsive whilst it is working. Kick the process off on a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) or similar and update / kick off stage 7 when you get a successful completion (or have to handle an error).

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start returns true when process has started added a do while loop and that should be it

```
  bool started = Process.Start(path)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e8zac0ca